# Can we restrict edit access of community /partner users?

Tags: community, permissions, partner-communities, user-management

I want to restrict edit access of community/partner portal users from internal user.

I have disabled "Manage users" permission and its dependant permissions from internal user's profile, but still I am able to edit the community/ partner user.

Do we have any other permission or its salesforce standard feature.

Comment: Is the user the owner of the Contact record for the community/partner portal users?

Comment: @DaveHumm No, the user is not owner of contact record

Answer (score 1):

You should try removing the 'Manage External Users' permission from the profile for this. Those users without it should not be able to edit a community or partner user without it.

Also check that the profile does not have 'Modify All Data' enabled.

[Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_DPUA.htm)

Comment: Yes I have already removed 'Manage External Users' permission from the profile also disabled 'Modify All Data' permission still I am able to edit a user for community and portal users.